# Default vue-cli build do not create css file

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

When I build my project, I can not find any css file. Unlike the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#app) says.

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib ***
```

I have three files : umd, umd.min and common.
And un message : "Images and other types of assets omitted".

Is there a special vuecli configuration to do?

I am experiencing this problem since I add unit tests in the project

Comment: Hello, which framework are you targeting 1.x or 2.x? or neither specifically?

Comment: Hi, vue-cli 2.5.16 in my dependencies. and I notice that three devDependencies are in this form:
`@vue/cli-service / cli-plugin-eslint": "^ 3.0.0-beta.11`
You think there may be a compatibility problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently and the following solutions worked for me:

1. Import the CSS file in the app entry, in my case, `src/App.vue`:
   `import './assets/scss/main.scss';`
2. Change the build command in the `package.json` file to target the entry file that imports the style:
   `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name index src/App.vue"`
3. Run `npm run build` or `yarn run build`.
4. Voilà!

The CSS file will appear.